# Remove Row from table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to generate a table with content of the array with an option to delete the rows. I got a basic block of code that I think that should work but it's not doing anything and it's giving me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" error.

```js
function newtest2() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
}

function newtest() {
  var name = ["Avengers", "Black Mirror", "Star Wars"];
  var r = name.length;
  $("#table1").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < r; i += 1) {

    $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + name[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button onclick='newtest2(this)'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");

  }
}
```

```css
#table1 {
  background: gray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">

</table>


<br>
<button onclick="newtest()">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `this` on the on HTML - `newtest2(this)`.

On your function, you need to recieve the variable and use it to delete the `<tr>`

```
 function newtest2(e) {              //Add e as parameter
      $(e).parents('tr').remove();   //Use the e to delete
 }
```

Here is the snippet:

```js
function newtest2(e) {
  $(e).parents('tr').remove();
}

function newtest() {
  var name = ["Avengers", "Black Mirror", "Star Wars"];
  var r = name.length;
  $("#table1").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < r; i += 1) {

    $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + name[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button onclick='newtest2(this)'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");

  }
}
```

```css
#table1 {
  background: gray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">

</table>


<br>
<button onclick="newtest()">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` doesn't refers to `TABLE`/`BUTTON` in the `newtest2()` method, it refers to *window* object thus the code didn't work.

Accept the *this* argument in function and use it

```
function newtest2(elem) {
   $(elem).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

```js
function newtest2(elem) {
  $(elem).closest('tr').remove();
}

function newtest() {
  var name = ["Avengers", "Black Mirror", "Star Wars"];
  var r = name.length;
  $("#table1").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < r; i += 1) {
    $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + name[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button onclick='newtest2(this)'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");
  }
}
```

```css
#table1 {
  background: gray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="newtest()">TEST</button>
```

---

I would recommend, you to use unobtrusive event handler use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to attach event handler with elements instead of ugly inline event handler.

Using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method with [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach to attach event handler for dynamic elements (Remove Button).

```js
$("#table1").on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})

$("#create").on('click', function() {
  var name = ["Avengers", "Black Mirror", "Star Wars"];
  var r = name.length;
  $("#table1").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < r; i += 1) {

    $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + name[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button class='remove' type='button'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");

  }
})
```

```css
#table1 {
  background: gray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">

</table>


<br>
<button id="create">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove a row on click of the button:

```
$('#table_id').on('click', '#remButton', function(){
    var indexRow = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("table_ID").deleteRow(indexRow);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify an argument in your function, and then you need to get the parent of the parent of the `this` element, because it is a button, and not the `<td>`.

Here is a working example. Note there might be a better way of doing this with click events and `id`s

```js
function newtest2(evt) {
  $(evt).parent().parent().remove();
}

function newtest() {
  var name = ["Avengers", "Black Mirror", "Star Wars"];
  var r = name.length;
  $("#table1").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < r; i += 1) {

    $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + name[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button onclick='newtest2(this)'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");

  }
}
```

```css
#table1 {
  background: gray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">

</table>


<br>
<button onclick="newtest()">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `$(this)` inside your function because it does not refer to the button being clicked.

Since you are including the function inside `onclick` and passing `this` as parameter, just use that parameter inside your function, like so

**Secondary suggestion:** use [.closest('tr')](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of [.parents('tr')](https://api.jquery.com/parents/), in case, you know, in the future you might want a table inside a table, ;)

```js
function newtest2(caller) {
  $(caller).closest('tr').remove();
}

function newtest() {
  var name = ["Avengers", "Black Mirror", "Star Wars"];
  var r = name.length;
  $("#table1").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < r; i += 1) {

    $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + name[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button onclick='newtest2(this)'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");

  }
}
```

```css
#table1 {
  background: gray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">

</table>


<br>
<button onclick="newtest()">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Change parent by closest. Parent is the immediate parent, closest is
  traversing the dom.
- *this* in the function newttest2 doesn't refer to the button
  element, just refer to it as a function parameter

```js
function newtest2(el) {
  $(el).closest('tr').remove();
}

function newtest() {
  var name = ["Avengers", "Black Mirror", "Star Wars"];
  var r = name.length;
  $("#table1").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < r; i += 1) {

    $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + name[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button onclick='newtest2(this)'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");

  }
}
```

```css
#table1 {
  background: gray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">

</table>


<br>
<button onclick="newtest()">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i += 1) {
                        $("#table1").append("<tr id=" + name[i] + "><td>" + name[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button id=" + name[i] + " onclick='newtest2(this.id)'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");
                    }



 function newtest2(id) {
            $('#' + id + '').remove();
        }
```